# I would like some order please (sites list in Filtered Questions rule)

Tags: feature-request, sorting, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

When adding new rule in [Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters), I get this for the list of all sites:

> [image]

This appears to be totally random. If I want to find a site, I must use the browser's search, or just scan the whole list.

Can this list please have some order? Alphabetic would be most intuitive, same like the list in the top bar "More Stack Exchange Communities" list.

Comment: @bluet good catch about missing MSE! Sounds like a valid bug report. Guess it's considered meta site of Stack Exchange itself, which is missing from the list because it's not really Q&A site, just a portal. You want to take the honor of reporting the bug? ;)

Comment: @bluet nice find! It was tagged incorrectly, fixed now. :)

Comment: Once you add a tag, it is sorted by tag popularity.  This question is after the custom tags field, I suppose they expect you to write custom tags first.

Comment: @gerrit thanks, never noticed. So the sort might be by total amount of questions or tags. Interesting.